# PHP Read the URL Then

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, search

I'd like to know is there a function that reads the url from the browser after that running a code;
for example I've this php code:

`echo "<a href='mypage.php?product=123456'>Search Result</a>";`

when hovering on the link the url should be like this:

```
http://yourdomain.com/mypage.php?product=123456
```

I want to retrieve data from the database of the search result that have a row contains:

```
123456
```

---

but let me explain to you;
let's say those are the search results

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

when hovering on the first result the url in the browser will be like this:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/mypage.php?product=1
```

I want to display all the data from the table that have a row which contains "1" by clicking on the result

thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put this to bed once and for all:

The first page:

```
//create the links:
$html=""
$sql="SELECT id,description FROM table";
$result=$mysqlidb->query($sql);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $html.=sprintf("<a href='mypage.php?product=%s'>%s</a><br>",$row['id'],$row['description']);
    }
echo $html;
```

The second page (mypage.php)

```
$product=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlidb,$_GET['product']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$product'"; //or use prepared statement but in this case this is faster;
$result=$mysqlidb->query($sql);
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

$row now contains the information you need and this can be inserted into your html format using sprintf along the lines of:

```
$html=sprintf("<SPAN id='1'>%s</SPAN><SPAN id='2'>%s</SPAN>...",$row['somestuff'],$row['otherstuff']);
```

How it all looks will depend on how you format the various html outputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can get id by,

```
$id = $_GET['product'];
```

And than fire query to retrieve data

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

Comment: You didn't just promote the fact that he should start out by coding insecure SQL injecting code, did you?

Comment: _'And than fire query to retrieve data'_ ...or destroy your whole database.

Comment: Yes this could cause an SQL injection

Comment: As everyone is implying do not use mysql_* functions because they are deprecated and you will come across them while looking up examples. Look into PDO or MySQLi instead.